# Cupy to speed up 4D plot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, optimization, cupy

I recently started looking at matplotlib to do some data visualization and understand better how some stats work in a game. This lead me to learn how to make 3D and then 4D visualization using matplotlib, but I quickly realized that the calculation speed is really an issue in this case.

This is still quite an easy function to compute, and using numpy I manage to get about 5fps, which isn't too bad but could definetly use some improvement.

My commented line 56 is my original working code, and I think that I understood the basics of vectorization but I'm certain I missed something as this code isn't working (error on line 57).

These are line 68 & 69, probably the source of the slowdown.

```
    Z = cp.array([fun(x, y, frame) for x, y in zip(cp.ravel(X), cp.ravel(Y))]).reshape(X.shape) # Current working way, slowing down using cupy because of the for loop.
    Z = cp.array(fun(X, Y, frame)) # My non-working attempt at vectorization.
```

The first line (normally commented, 68) is my original working code, but is not making a good GPU usage. I think that I understood the idea of vectorization but I'm certain I missed something as the next line, supposed to replace it, isn't working (69).
It gives me the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`.

How would I go about making my code "GPU-ready" so that it works with cupy ?

Here is the full program. A lot of the commented lines are just for easier switch back to 3D arrays.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm
import time
import cupy as cp
from line_profiler import LineProfiler


def main():
    # Init
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16, 9), dpi=80)
    ax = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")
    # fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 9), projection="3d")
    SCALE = 1000.0

    def fun(x, y, w):
        # return x**2 + y
        return x * (1 + (max((y - w), 0) * 0.01))  # Graph EHP

    funK = cp.ElementwiseKernel(
        "float64 x, float64 y, float64 w",
        "float64 r",
        """
        r = y - w;
        if (r < 0)
        {
            r = 0;
        }
        r = x * (1 + r * 0.01);
        """,
    )

    # Change background colors

    # ax.set_axis_off()
    ax.set_yticks([0, SCALE * 0.25, SCALE * 0.5, SCALE * 0.75, SCALE])
    ax.set_xticks([0, SCALE * 0.25, SCALE * 0.5, SCALE * 0.75, SCALE])
    # ax.set_zticks([0, fun(SCALE, SCALE) * 0.25, fun(SCALE, SCALE) * 0.5, fun(SCALE, SCALE) * 0.75, fun(SCALE, SCALE)])
    # ax.set_frame_on(False)
    BCK_COLOR = (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)
    TXT_COLOR = (0.0, 0.8, 0.8)
    FRAMES = 10
    ax.tick_params(which="both", color=TXT_COLOR, labelcolor=TXT_COLOR, grid_color=BCK_COLOR)
    ax.set_facecolor(BCK_COLOR)
    fig.set_facecolor(BCK_COLOR)

    # Generate data
    x = y = cp.arange(0.0, SCALE, SCALE / 100)
    X, Y = cp.meshgrid(x, y)

    # 3D only array populating.
    # zs = cp.array([fun(x, y) for x, y in zip(cp.ravel(X), cp.ravel(Y))])
    # Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

    # Manage side labels
    ax.set_xlabel("Health", color=TXT_COLOR)
    ax.set_ylabel("Defense", color=TXT_COLOR)
    ax.set_zlabel("EHP", color=TXT_COLOR)

    # 4D (time) plotting.
    current_frame = None
    tstart = time.time()
    for frame in np.linspace(1, SCALE, FRAMES):
        # If a line collection is already remove it before drawing.
        if current_frame:
            current_frame.remove()
        # Generate data.
        # Z = cp.array([funK(x, y, frame) for x, y in zip(cp.ravel(X), cp.ravel(Y))]).reshape(X.shape)
        # Z = fun(X.all(), Y.all(), frame)
        Z = funK(X, Y, frame) #vectorized way, taking full advantage of the GPU. Near 0 runtime.
        ax.set_zticks(
            [
                0,
                fun(SCALE, SCALE, frame) * 0.25,
                fun(SCALE, SCALE, frame) * 0.5,
                fun(SCALE, SCALE, frame) * 0.75,
                fun(SCALE, SCALE, frame),
            ]
        )
        # Plot the new wireframe and pause briefly before continuing.
        cp.cuda.Stream.null.synchronize()
        current_frame = ax.plot_surface(
            X.get(), Y.get(), Z.get(), cmap=cm.plasma, linewidth=0.1, antialiased=True, alpha=0.9
        )
        plt.pause(0.001)
    print("Average FPS: %f" % (FRAMES / (time.time() - tstart)))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    lp = LineProfiler()
    lp_wrapper = lp(main)
    lp_wrapper()
    lp.print_stats()
```

Edit : Updated code. Now using a CUDA Kernel and passing through a lineprofiler to record performance. 50% of the processing time is on the line 68 (generating `Z` through list comprehension), so the problem can be narrowed down to

How to generate a 2D array by passing all the combinaisons or two arrays through a function/CUDA Kernel in a "cupy way" ?

I also have potential to shave of time in last 5 lines, as they also take nearly 40% to draw the graph, but I don't think there is much to do as I/O is always terribly slow.

2nd edit : Updated code again. I figured out the CuPy array! I forgot that I am already creating a meshgrid before, and can simply pass it through my kernel with the current frame to get all the combinaisons of X,Y coordinates, thus making `Z = funK(X, Y, frame)` complete and valid. I think I missed this as I was trying to use normal functions before understanding that this is the only option to use the GPU.

The only improvements left to do are in the rendering using matplotlib, and I don't know if it is possible to make use of the GPU there. I will update this main code until I reached my optimization objective.

Comment: I think the problem is the function use `max`. Did you tried with `cp.maximum`? Besides, please note that `/100` is certainly slower than `*0.01`. Also please note that Cupy will certainly create many temporary arrays like Numpy does and this is inefficient since the computation will be memory bound. CPUs are good for simple-precision computationally-intensive operations, not much for double-precision memory-bound ones. I advise you to try to write a CUDA kernel for better performance.

Comment: Another possible performance issue comes from sending/receiving data to/from the GPU for every frame which is generally slow. I expect the matplotlib plotting to be the main bottleneck here. I wonder if a simple Numba code would not be competitive or actually faster than your Cupy code (I am pretty sure this is the case on a mainstream client-side GPU at least).

Comment: I just tried with `cp.maximum` and got an error. I don't think this one would be too much of an issue since it is only making sure that I don't end up with a negative number there.

From what I understand, on GPU I/O I only have the output of my array, and the input of the number in "frame", so if this is a bottleneck, then an alternative to matplotlib would be preferrable. From what I understood though, it most likely has to do with the "for" loop in the list comprehension that I used before, which is not working with vectorized computation

Comment: use `line_profiler` to check what is your problem, no need to guess

Comment: I didn't know about line_profiler! Amazing! I have about 5% of time in init which is fine, but almost 50% on that single line I was talking about (the one using list comprehension to generate a frame). I also have 27% of time spent on the `plt.pause` and 16% on making the plot for the frame. I will update the original post accordingly, and add my newly coded CUDA kernel